# Tensorflow Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll' without explicitly loading them

Tags: python, tensorflow, ctypes

When I import tensorflow I saw the following errors.

```
>>> import tensorflow
[WinError 87] 参数错误。
[WinError 87] 参数错误。
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 51, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
>>>
```

I installed vcredist but it does not work.

But after I tried to load these DLLs with `ctypes` using absolute path, it works.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140_1.dll")
<WinDLL 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140_1.dll', handle 7fff7ddb0000 at 0x1f31e10e430>
>>> ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll")
<WinDLL 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll', handle 7fff69e30000 at 0x1f3212918b0>
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
>>>
```

I'm confused about the causes of such a problem and want to know how to solve this.

`C:\Windows\System32\` and `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\` is in my PATH env.

```
where msvcp140.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\msvcp140.dll
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\msvcp140.dll
```

Comment: Hi @Cat ALog, Please install Microsoft Visual C++ as mentioned in the error and in the Software requiremnets in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) to setup Tensorflow with GPU. Please verify the Hardware/Software requirements required for GPU support and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the same link. Note -  TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Thank you.